# Taylor Series centred at some value.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

The Taylor Series for $\bf{e}^x$ centred at $x=0$ is:$${{\bf{e}}^x} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty {\frac{{{x^n}}}{{n!}}}$$

Now lets say I let $x=100$, will the Taylor Series above give me the correct value for $\bf{e^{100}}$ since I have centered it at $x=0$ ?

Does centering the Taylor series at any number limit me in any way?

Comment: The Taylor series itself (with all terms) will give the exact value for any number $x$, since it is the definition of $\mathrm e^x$. However, in  practice, you can compute only a finite number of terms, and there may be more efficient algorithms for for such values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the exponential function, the answer is negative. It turns out that, for *every* $x\in\mathbb R$, $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Comment: What about the series I will get if I centre it at $x=2$, will that work for all $x$?

Comment: Yes, it will. ${}$